# Does a flooded moon condition essentially mean you have less time to leave?

Tags: lethal-company

Every time you land on a moon, you have until midnight to leave. I played on March with the "Flooded" condition, which seems to slowly flood out the moons surface as time goes on.

It was around 5:00pm and the entire ship was stranded out in an **ocean**. I tried to get back to it, but drowned (you can't swim above the water as far as I could tell, only very slowly walk in it).

Does a "Flooded" condition essentially mean you have less time to extract since you'll end up drowning trying to reach the ship (at least on March) if you take too long?